# ruby on rails overriding equals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model user.rb (it's an ActiveRecord::Base, not sure if its relevant to the discussion)

In certain views, I compare two users via:

```
<% if current_user == user %>
```

The result is undeterministic(sometimes the result is true, and sometimes it's false), and I'm not sure why.

If I switch it to

```
<% if current_user.id == user.id %>
```

It works as expected. But then I need to handle the case where the user(s) can be null.

My question is, what's going on here?

Why does user1 == user2 fail here?

Should I be overriding == , or

Should I be using an alternative method such as equal?, ===, or eql?

Shouldn't the fact that user.rb is an ActiveRecord::Base mean == by default compares the id fields already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `==`

```
      # File lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2427
2427:       def ==(comparison_object)
2428:         comparison_object.equal?(self) ||
2429:           (comparison_object.instance_of?(self.class) &&
2430:             comparison_object.id == id &&
2431:             !comparison_object.new_record?)
2432:       end
```

You can see that it should return true when the object ids match. If your code `<% if current_user == user %>` is failing for the same user object you have definitely got something odd going on.

Can you post that code snippet in context?

Comment: thank you for the snippet, definitely reassuring to look at. Since it's just a straight up comparison,  It's hard to give short relevant beyond what I've included in the original question. Let me dig around more...

Comment: @tstyle put this in your code and let us know what you get: if current_user != user; puts user.inspect; puts current_user.inspect; end

Comment: Hey @DanSingerman sorry I just totally forgot about coming back to this question. Eventually got it working by overriding == in the user object with code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-%3D%3D

> Returns true if comparison_object is
>   the same exact object, or
>   comparison_object is of the same type
>   and self has an ID and it is equal to
>   comparison_object.id.
>
> Note that new records are different
>   from any other record by definition,
>   unless the other record is the
>   receiver itself. Besides, if you fetch
>   existing records with select and leave
>   the ID out, you’re on your own, this
>   predicate will return false.
>
> Note also that destroying a record
>   preserves its ID in the model
>   instance, so deleted models are still
>   comparable.

It should match `current_user == user`

How are you fetching current_user object?

Comment: when the user signs in, I save his id in a permanent cookie as "saved_id". Then inside current_user, I return User.find_by_id(saved_id). Since current_user.id == user.id seem to be working, I believe I am returning the correct "current user"

Comment: could you try printing `user.class` and `current_user.class` and post the output?

Comment: I added these lines, <%= debug current_user.class %>
<%= debug wish.user.class %>, right before the comparision, and they both print User(id: integer, name: string, email: string...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go further on equality in ruby, take a look at this very good blog post:

http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/

Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: This is a question about '==' in Ruby on Rails. Rails overrides Ruby's '==', so for this question this answer is very much a red herring. RoR == only uses Ruby's == for comparing integers.